# Creating a tar archive without including the parent directory when files are stored in different directories

Tags: tar

I have the following four files in the file system:

```
/home/martin/cvs/ops/cisco/b/s1
/home/martin/cvs/ops/cisco/b/s2
/home/martin/cvs/ops/extreme/b/r3
/home/martin/cvs/ops/j/b/r5
```

I need to put those files into a tar archive, but I don't want to add directories. The best I could come up with was:

```
tar -C ~/cvs/ops/ -czvf archive.tgz cisco/b/s1 cisco/b/s2 extreme/b/r3 j/b/r5
```

This is still not perfect, because each file in the archive is two directories deep. Is there a better way? Or do I simply have to copy `s1`, `s2`, `r3` and `r5` files into one directory and create the archive with `tar -czvf archive.tgz s1 s2 r3 r5`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `-C` multiple times (moving from one directory to another):

```
tar czvf archive.tar.gz -C /home/martin/cvs/ops/cisco/b s1 s2 -C ../../extreme/b r3 -C ../../j/b r5
```

Note that each `-C` option is interpreted relative to the current directory *at that point* (or you can just use absolute paths).

Answer (score 11):

If you have the list of files in a file, or can generate them using a command, you can use a single GNU tar command:

```
tar cf foo.tar -T list-of-files --transform 's:.*/::'
```

The transform still keeps directories, but flattens the layout completely. So you need some way of filtering directories, hence the need of a list of files.

Answer (score 8):

You could append files to the archive one by one:

```
tar cf /tmp/archive.tar -C /home/martin/cvs/ops/cisco/b s1
tar rf /tmp/archive.tar -C /home/martin/cvs/ops/cisco/b s2
tar rf /tmp/archive.tar -C /home/martin/cvs/ops/extreme/b r3
tar rf /tmp/archive.tar -C /home/martin/cvs/ops/j/b r5
```

You could script this to make it easier: for each path, run `tar rf` with the base directory as the value for the `-C` parameter and the base filename without path to add.